# “Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry” error when attempting to install py2exe-0.6.9 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I'm trying to install **py2exe-0.6.9** on **Windows 10**, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Python Version 2.7 required which was not found in the registry
```

I have already installed **python 2.7.14** and have the path correctly configured:  
When I type python on cmd on whatever directory, python interpreter runs.

Any advices please

Comment: Did you install it using the Windows installer package, or in some other way.?

Comment: You get this message when your installation of Python is not the same bitness (32/64) as the package you are trying to install. The registry settings for 32-bit apps are not where you might expect them but instead are in a subnode of `Software\Wow6432Node`.

Comment: thaïs a lot, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks @BoarGules your answer did help

I switched from **py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe** to **py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe** and it worked like a charm.